# .valid() doesn't work when the form is submitted the second time with AJAX

Tags: jquery, validation

The client side validation works perfectly when I submit the form the first time but when I submit it again after being successfully submitted, it doesn't do the client side validation. I can't figure out what the problem is.
This is part of my code:

```
 function SubmitProjectDetails(e) {
        var detailsForm = $('#project-details-form');
        if (!detailsForm.valid() || !$("#project-details-form select.chosen-select").valid()) {  //Need to check the selects that are hidden by the chosen framework specially or they will be ignored
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#project-details-form select.chosen-select").each(function (){
                if (! $(this).valid()) {
                    $("#" + $(this).prop("id") + "_chosen a").addClass("input-validation-error");
                }
            });
            var v = detailsForm.validate();
            $("#project-details-form select.chosen-select").on("change blur",
                function() {
                    var element = $("#" + $(this).prop("id"));
                    $("#" + $(this).prop("id") + "_chosen a").removeClass("input-validation-error");
                   v.element(element);
                 });
            return;
        }
        $("#project-details-return-message").html("");
        var id = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ProjectDetailsViewModel?.Project?.Id));
        if (id != null) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#project-details-container").html("<h1 style='color:grey'>Loading...</h1>");
            $.ajax({
                type: detailsForm.attr('method'),
                url: detailsForm.attr('action'),
                data: detailsForm.serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#project-details-container").html(data);
                    putAsterisksOnRequiredFields();
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    $("#project-details-container").html("<h1 style='color:red'>Ajax Error!</h1>");
                    console.log('An ajax error occurred.');
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The second form validation is not correct. `this` refers to the select with the class `chosen-select` (because that's what you selected with the previous jQuery selector `$("#project-details-form select.chosen-select")`).

What you could do is to create a boolean variable containing the valid state of the form and then use it in your conditions.

Here's an example:

```
var detailsFormValid = detailsForm.valid();
if (!detailsFormValid  || !$("#project-details-form select.chosen-select").valid()) {
     e.preventDefault();
        $("#project-details-form select.chosen-select").each(function (){
            if (!detailsFormValid) {
                $("#" + $(this).prop("id") + "_chosen a").addClass("input-validation-error");
            }
        });
        var v = detailsForm.validate();
        $("#project-details-form select.chosen-select").on("change blur",
            function() {
                var element = $("#" + $(this).prop("id"));
                $("#" + $(this).prop("id") + "_chosen a").removeClass("input-validation-error");
               v.element(element);
             });
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but it still didn't solve the issue. On the second time I submit , I also have to refer to the select with the class chosen-select .

Comment: I just noticed that your variable `v` could be a problem. the `.validate()` function initializes jQuery validate without checking if there are any errors in your form. So it should be done before calling your function. I think you probably meant `v = detailsForm.valid()` to get the boolean. In my answer, I already put it in a variable called detailsFormValid, so you can try to delete your variable decalaration and replace the `v.element(element)` by `detailsFormValid.element(element)`.

Comment: I tried doing what you said and it still doesn't work.thanks.